# How many channels can be opened with a lightning node simultaneously

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I set up a bitcoin lightning network on my local machine. How many channels can be created simultaneously with my lightning node. Will creating too many channel connection affect channel functionality? Does this depends on implementation (lnd, clightning or eclair)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical limit on the number of channels your one node can open.

However, for each channel you open, you are 'locking up' some bitcoin. It is suggested around 500,000 sats per channel is needed (https://kroisos.io/how-many-sats-should-you-put-in-a-lightning-channel/) and as such, as of today, that's almost $300 right now.

So, there might be a limit to your funds :)